# How to add tutorial to a flutter app when we launch it for the first time

Tags: flutter

Anyone knows how to add tutorial when the app is launched for the first time in flutter? Example is attached as an image.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [tutorial_coach_mark](https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark) library,like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_coach_mark/tutorial_coach_mark.dart';

void showTutorial() {
    TutorialCoachMark(
      context,
      targets: targets, // List<TargetFocus>
      colorShadow: Colors.red, // DEFAULT Colors.black
       // alignSkip: Alignment.bottomRight,
       // textSkip: "SKIP",
       // paddingFocus: 10,
      finish: (){
        print("finish");
      },
      clickTarget: (target){
        print(target);
      },
      clickSkip: (){
        print("skip");
      }
    )..show();
  }
```

To be able to use it for the first time you need the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var watchedIntro=prefs.getBool('watchedIntro')??false;
if(!watchedIntro)
```

and when the tutorial ended set `watchedIntro` to true:

```
await prefs.setBool('watchedIntro', true);
```

Comment: Will this work only first time when we launch the app?

Comment: How to change color of the background? Its always red

Comment: Also what you wrote  so that i can use it for the first time is throwing 12 errors. I copied pasted the example in the pub.dev and then pasted what you wrote.

Comment: @Priyank Look at their github pages. you can find info about how to use them

Comment: I tried but didn't find how to change the color or how to use it for thr first time or when the app launches. Kindly help

Comment: try any youtube tutorial to add tutorial to your flutter app.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out this package, [tutorial_coach_mark](https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark).

Comment: How to change color of the background? Its always red